# Why does draw() in pygraphviz/agraph not work on the server (but locally)?

Tags: python-3.x, pygraphviz, graph-drawing

I have a Python app using Pygraphviz that works fine locally, but on the server the `draw` function throws an error. It happens in [`make_svg`](https://github.com/watchduck/DAG/blob/master/back/proj/app/utils/make_svg.py). The following lines are the relevant part of the errors I get. (The full trail is [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/yJKRXtWH).)

```
File "/path/to/app/utils/make_svg.py", line 17, in make_svg
  prog='dot'
File "/path/to/pygraphviz/agraph.py", line 1477, in draw
  fh = self._get_fh(path, 'w+b')
File "/path/to/pygraphviz/agraph.py", line 1506, in _get_fh
  fh = open(path, mode=mode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'app/svg_files/nope.svg'
```

Logging `type(g)` gives `<class 'pygraphviz.agraph.AGraph'>` as expected.

I work in a virtualenv in a `mod_wsgi 4.6.5/Python3.7` environment on a Webfaction server.
Locally I use a virtualenv with Python 3.5.
The version of Pygraphviz is 1.3.1.
(First I had 1.5 on the server. The error was exactly the same, except for the line numbers.)

What can I do?

The same error is described in [this bug report](https://github.com/mandatoryprogrammer/TrustTrees/issues/2) from last year.
I don't get which directory I am supposed to create. `svg_files` exists and has rights 777.

The `draw` function at the end of `make_svg` should create the SVG.
(And at the end of [`extract_coordinates_from_svg`](https://github.com/watchduck/DAG/blob/master/back/proj/app/utils/extract_coordinates_from_svg.py) the file is removed again.)
The file name is a hash created in [`connected_dag`](https://github.com/watchduck/DAG/blob/master/back/proj/app/utils/connected_dag.py) (`svg_name`).

Comment: Upload the file nope.svg to app/svg_files/ on the server...

Comment: The creation of this SVG on the server is what fails. I clarified that in the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the server `app/svg_files` seems not to describe the same place as locally.
I defined the path unambiguously, and now it works.

```
file_path = '{grandparent}/svg_files/{name}.svg'.format(
    grandparent=os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
    name=name
)
g.draw(file_path, prog='dot')
```